# Qual software uso para modelar imagens deste tipo?

Tags: modelagem

Procuro um software para modelar estrutura/formas 3D, de preferencia simples, um que não necessite conhecimento profundo em computação gráfica... mas à nível de usuário avançado.

Exemplo imagem:

[image: Imagem 1]

Comment: Olá Pedro. Em minha opinião a sua pergunta foi satisfatoriamente respondida (Blender é uma ótima ferramenta!). Mas a sua pergunta não está no escopo do site, que é voltado à programação. Se ainda não o fez, por favor faça o [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serve o blender?
https://www.blender.org/features/

É livre e tem uma comunidade brasileira. Inclusive com tutoriais em português: http://www.blender.com.br/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=42&Itemid=147